# Collecting total charge value where custom field is X

Tags: templating, plugin-charge

I'm using Charge to collect donations toward individual projects for a charity.

On the frontend, I want to display how much has been raised for an individual project.

To get a list of charges for a project, I'm doing

```
{% set charges = craft.charge.charges({  
      search : { query : 'projectDonateTo:' ~ entry.id }}
   )%}

{% for charge in charges %}
    {{ charge.amount }}
{% endfor %}
```

which obviously loops through all charges but I can't fathom how to total these together.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not do:

```
{% set total = 0 %}

{% for charge in charges %}
    {% set total = total + charge.amount %}
{% endfor %}

{{ total|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}
```

?

Comment: OK - it did but need to `{% set total = total + charge.amount %}` for it to work. If you want to edit the answer, I'll mark it off.